# How to show that this language is decidable

Tags: solution-verification, computer-science, context-free-grammar, turing-machines, decidability

**The question :**

The language is $L=$ { $< G,w > $ : $G$ is a grammar in normal form of Chomsky and $w$ is a word on the terminal alphabet that can be derivated in $G$ by at least 2 differents derivations trees. }

In other words, find an algorithm that when given a grammar that is in normal form of Chomsky and a word $w$, it concludes after a finite number of steps if yes or no $w$ can be derivated by two derivations trees.

**My reflexion and attempt:**

Since the grammar is in Chomsky normal form, we know that it will take exactly $2|w|-1$ steps of derivation. So everything is done in a finite time space.

So we have to take our string and be able to derivate it with two derivation tree.

The part i am not sure in the algorithm is how to say that we are switching the derivations rules used ( so we don't get the same derivation tree).

**Here's my attempt but it seems odd:**

Entry : < G, w >;

1. Try every derivations in $G$ of length $2|w| -1$.
2. If two derivations generate w stop and accept < G,w >. Else stop and reject < G,w >.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I would try every derivations and increase a counter if that derives $w$. If the counter is $\le 1$, reject.

Comment: @Berci Thanks for reply, yea that's a good idea, but i am not sure if we can use a counter in that type of problems  ? Or at least i have never seen one in the examples seen. Also i changed the step two, cause i just realized that you don't need to redo all the derivations.

Comment: You can have 3 identical states somehow (the last one included in the 'accepting' states), one for the case no derivation of $w$ is computed yet, one for the case of the first derivation, and the last state for $\ge 2$ derivations.

Comment: @Berci i am not sure how to translate this into an algorithm, does my algorithm in my post work ? If not what is wrong thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I’m afraid the “try every derivations” part of your attempt is a bit imprecise.  The idea is there, but how would you do it?  Well, there is a well-known dynamic programming algorithm that “tries every derivation” in time $O(n^3)$: [the CYK algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm).

The algorithm, from Wikipedia, is as follows:

```
let the input be a string I consisting of n characters: a1 ... an.
let the grammar contain r nonterminal symbols R1 ... Rr, with start symbol R1.
let P[n,n,r] be an array of booleans. Initialize all elements of P to false.

for each s = 1 to n
    for each unit production Rv → as
        set P[1,s,v] = true

for each l = 2 to n -- Length of span
    for each s = 1 to n-l+1 -- Start of span
        for each p = 1 to l-1 -- Partition of span
            for each production Ra → Rb Rc
                if P[p,s,b] and P[l-p,s+p,c] then set P[l,s,a] = true

if P[n,1,1] is true then
    I is member of language
else
    I is not member of language
```

However, in this basic form, the CYK algorithm is a mere recognizer – it will only tell you if a word belongs to the grammar or not.  To get what we’re after, we need to do some bookkeeping.  Instead of booleans, we can store the parse trees in the $P[l, s, v]$ array.  Here is a modification to the pseudo-code:

```
let the input be a string I consisting of n characters: a1 ... an.
let the grammar contain r nonterminal symbols R1 ... Rr, with start symbol R1.
let P[n,n,r] be an array of lists. Initialize all elements of P to the empty list.
let TerminalNode(Rv,as) denote a terminal node with production Rv → as
let NonTerminalNode(Ra,Rb,Rc) denote a nonterminal node with production Ra → Rb Rc

for each s = 1 to n
    for each unit production Rv → as
        append TerminalNode(Rv,as) to P[1,s,v]

for each l = 2 to n -- Length of span
    for each s = 1 to n-l+1 -- Start of span
        for each p = 1 to l-1 -- Partition of span
            l_cell = P[p,s,b]
            r_cell = P[l-p,s+p,c]
            for each production Ra → Rb Rc
                l_nodes = [node in l_cell | node.symbol = Rb]
                r_nodes = [node in r_cell | node.symbol = Rc]
                for each l_node in l_nodes
                    for each r_node in r_nodes
                        append NonTerminalNode(Ra,l_node,r_node) to P[l,s,a]
```

Now, $P[n, 1, 1]$ tells you the entire *parse forest* that was used to derive the string.  From here, you can easily determine if the derivation was ambiguous or not.

Comment: Thanks for reply, mm maybe i am misunderstood we just need to give a pseudo code algorithm, since it's a theoretical computer science class, we saw automaton, languages, etc. Now were studying turing machine, and i need to give a pseudo code algorithm ( usually from examples we've seen its like 2-4 lines) so we don't have to find a specific algorithm like the one you gave. We need to use properties grammar given and other concepts seen in class).

Comment: We're not asked to dive deep into an algorithm, we just want to prove that it stops and accept or stop and reject with an algorithm that works.

Comment: Alright then, [in your comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3925359/how-to-show-that-this-language-is-decidable/3926739?noredirect=1#comment8097641_3925359) you said you wanted to translate your idea to an algorithm – that algorithm is exactly the CYK algorithm.

Comment: But if you’re looking for a simpler solution, then so be it.  I’d also be interested to see it.  Ambiguity is not a simple problem!

Comment: the idea (i think) is to use the fact that it's in normal form of chomsky $2|w| -1$ so we know there's a finite steps of derivaitons ( good thing to be decidable), so since we have all the derivations ( for sure they are differents) and i think we can juste check if there's two derivations that generate the word w. But i am not sure.